# Powershell PnP error converting Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web object

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, patterns-and-practices

I am trying out Franck Cornu's O365StarterIntranet, from Patterns and Practices (PnP).

I have updated to the latest PnP powershell Online, the latest SharePoint Online SDK.

Most of the things work fine, but this is the error I get. When calling "Enable-CustomItemScheduling"

```
"Cannot convert the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web" value of type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web" to type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web"
```

It seems that the web object gotten from "Get-SPOWeb" or "Get-PnPWeb" (tried both) cannot convert to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web.

As you can se below, the function expects a "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web".

```
function Enable-CustomItemScheduling {
[CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]$Web,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$PagesLibraryName
    )
```

The function is called like this, where Get-PnPWeb is the same as Get-SPOWeb in former PnP powershell releases:

```
Enable-CustomItemScheduling -Web (Get-PnPWeb) -PagesLibraryName "Pages"
```

Have you any idea on how I can fix this and where to look?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
function Enable-CustomItemScheduling {
[CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [OfficeDevPnP.Core.PnPClientContext]$CurrentContext,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$PagesLibraryName
    )
```

and then use the context to get the web

```
Enable-CustomItemScheduling --Web $CurrentContext.Web -PagesLibraryName "Pages"
```